# SEO Affected by Sizes Attribute in Images

Tags: seo, google-pagespeed, core-web-vitals

If we set `sizes="(max-width: 450px) 50vw")` of the image but later we will expand this image to full width. Will google penalize us for it as we expanded the image to `100vw` but told Google to download `50vw` via sizes?

`<img src="/images/ac10.jpg"  srcset="/images1/ac10-m4.jpg 800w ,/images/ac10.jpg 1100w" sizes="(max-width: 450px) 250px,1100px">`

I want to counter higher DPR devices via the sizes attribute. If we set `sizes="(max-width: 450px) 100vw")` then on iPhoneX (DPR=3), Google will download (375*3 or 1125px) wide image which is huge. But if we set `sizes="(max-width: 450px) 50vw")` and later stretch image to `width:100%` then it will download (1125/2 px) wide image which will dramatically improve load time.

I want to know if this is cheating in Google's eyes as we are tricking google to download a 50vw size image and later we are using it as a 100vw size image. Will it affect SEO?

Comment: I think you must go to the google support forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it at all.

The biggest red flag for Google is if you're checking the User-agent and delivering different content specifically for Googlebot.

When it comes to cloaking Google is looking for deceitfulness. What you're doing doesn't sound deceitful, it sounds more like a progressive enhancement if anything.

If you're using Javascript to switch out the images, then Google probably is picking it up anyway, which should be fine.

Comment: I will not use JS. I want to download the 50vw size of the image through the sizes attribute and later stretch it using CSS like this img{ width:100%}.

Comment: @GauravYadav I see. Still this doesn't sound like it will be an issue.